# Newly installed Ubuntu doesn't recognize second monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.02 today, everything worked fine expect for the fact that it doesn't seem to be recognizing my second monitor at all. It seems to be a very common problem with Nvidia GPU's but I still haven't found a working solution.

I already tried: installing lightdm, blacklist nouveau, and also downgrading to an old stable version (I tried 390).

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that this thread might help? I would like to comment it but I can't so here you go :
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/140663/ubuntu-not-detecting-second-monitor#:~:text=System%20Settings%20%3E%20Additional%20Drivers.&text=Below%20are%20the%20steps%20that,Plug%2Din%20the%20second%20display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140663/ubuntu-not-detecting-second-monitor#:%7E:text=System%20Settings%20%3E%20Additional%20Drivers.&text=Below%20are%20the%20steps%20that,Plug%2Din%20the%20second%20display).

Comment: Unfortunately no that doesn't help.