# Ubuntu 22.04.2 not recognizing 2nd monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I recently bought a new ASUS ROG Strix laptop and did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04. Everything was fine until I plugged in my 2nd monitor through HDMI. I wasn't able to get it to work no matter what. Specs of my laptop are as follows.

[image: system info]

Ubuntu doesn't even detect the monitor itself. This is the output of `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.00  
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1440x900     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00  
   1024x768     144.00  
   800x600      144.00  
   640x480      144.00  
DisplayPort-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Even when I go to Display settings, it says only the built-in display is connected.

[image: Display settings]

I had already installed the NVIDIA display drivers exactly according to what [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304132/1546491) answer tells before I encountered this issue. (I tried everything answer on this question and [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-doesnt-detect-my-second-hdmi-display/75076/94) as well)

`nvidia-smi`

```
Wed Aug  9 11:10:45 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.98                 Driver Version: 535.98       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P8               3W /  65W |    365MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1682      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          107MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1850      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                        101MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3373      G   ...irefox/2356/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      143MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6794      G   gnome-control-center                          1MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Nvidia settings:

[image: nvidia settings]

Nothing happens even when I click **Detect Displays**.

Also I tried installing Debian on this laptop as well. It had the exact same issue. My final goal is to be able to use my 2nd monitor alongside Ubuntu.

Comment: Your provided details show a non-updated Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS system; did you try upgrading it fully?  (22.04.2 used the 5.19 HWE kernel that is now EOL; with 22.04.3 using the 6.2 HWE kernel OR 5.15 GA kernel stack - what stacks did you try as you didn't specify & only provided details of an non-updated Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system).

Comment: Just installed the update and the issue remains the same. Not sure what you meant by "stacks"

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack options; with the *default* stack selected by the ISO you use to install (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).  If used *live*, 22.04 & 22.04.1 all contained the 5.15 kernel, 22.04.2 used 5.19 (*if Desktop ISO*), 22.04.3 used 6.2 (*again if Desktop ISO; installs got that late last week or last weekend with ISO release in a number of hours*) if using HWE (*hardware enablement or newer stacks*), or remained 5.15 if using the GA kernel stack.  5.19 was from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04 etc which is available for the prior LTS.  Server defaults GA.

Comment: Its Desktop stack i presume, and after the update its 22.04.3
```
kavi@local:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

```

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop ISOs default to HWE  (`uname -r` will show what you're running, eg. mine reports as `6.2.0-26-generic` and given I'm on *jammy* or 22.04 - I see I booted using the HWE stack as I have both HWE + GA installed), however *flavors* like Lubuntu/Xubuntu.. default to GA if 22.04 or 22.04.1 media was used; and HWE only if 22.04.2 or later was used.  5.15 is the GA kernel for 22.04.3, 6.2 the HWE kernel for 22.04.3, with other OEM kernel stack options also existing too. HWE allows us to have a newer stack (*better for newer hardware*), GA an older stack that is more *stable*...

Comment: SO your recommendation would be to go with HWE because it would be better with newer hardware?

Comment: Best is *subjective*, but generally it's the OEM options (*if they exist; as the maker/OEM was involved in the decision!*), then usually HWE on newer hardware (*why Ubuntu Desktop made it the default for 20.04 & later*), for *stability* (*and not display graphics*) it's GA (*why Servers use GA*) but you can install them all (*this box of mine has GA + HWE*) though some closed-source kernel modules can prevent this (*some Nvidia kernel modules for example*) & there is always hardware that likes one stack better than another - thus we have choice to select our kernel stack (on LTS releases)